# get all attributes from nodes with same name

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an xml-file with products.
I have split it up into a table with one row for each product with product number and xml

```
SKU |  xml
----|-------
1111|<product><price>123</price....</product>
1112|<product><price>345</price....</product>
```

The attributes are stored like this:

```xml
<attribute-list>
    <attribute name="tax_id" attribute-type="integer"><value default="1">2</value></attribute>
        <attribute name="weight" attribute-type="integer"><value default="1">258</value></attribute>
        <attribute name="length" attribute-type="integer"><value default="1">180</value></attribute>
        <attribute name="width" attribute-type="integer"><value default="1">115</value></attribute>
        <attribute name="height" attribute-type="integer"><value default="1">15</value></attribute>
        <attribute name="series_name" attribute-type="string"><value language-id="DE" default="1"><![CDATA[CSV]]></value></attribute>
        <attribute name="country_of_origin_code" attribute-type="string"><value default="1">LT</value></attribute>
        <attribute name="number_of_pages" attribute-type="string"><value default="1">288</value></attribute>
...
</attribute-list>
```

Different products may have different attributes, for instance shoe-size is not relevant for a book :-)

I'd like to select all possible attribute-names.

```
attr
----
weight
length
number_of_pages
shoe_size
```

I can get all the possible values for a given attribute-name

```sql
select distinct xml.value('(/product/attribute-list/attribute[@name="color"])[1]',
'varchar(100)') as colors from product_xml
```

I'm getting close with

```sql
 SELECT distinct cast(T2.attr.query('.') as nvarchar(max))
 FROM   product_xml
 CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('/product/attribute-list/attribute') as T2(attr)
```

Here I get a record for each possible attribute-name and value

So I'm just missing the last step of only getting the name.

EDIT: The quick-and-dirty version is here:

```sql
;with p as (SELECT distinct cast(T2.attr.query('.') as nvarchar(max)) at
FROM   product_xml
CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('/product/attribute-list/attribute') as T2(attr)) 
select distinct left(at,CHARINDEX('>',at)) from p
```

This produces each attribute in a record by itself, which I can then manipulate in the application (php), Not as clean as just getting the name alone, but easily parsed, and only to be used very rarely.

```xml
<attribute name="age_rating" attribute-type="string">
<attribute name="aroma" attribute-type="string">
<attribute name="barcode" attribute-type="string">
<attribute name="barcode_type" attribute-type="string">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? This statement lists all `@name` attributes for each attribute, and then also grabs the actual `Value` as well as the `@DefaultValue` from the `<Value>` subnode:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
    AttrName = XC.value('@name', 'varchar(50)'),
    DefaultValue=XC.value('(value/@default)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Value=XC.value('(value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    product_xml
CROSS APPLY
    xml.nodes('/product/attribute-list/attribute') AS XT(XC)
```

This shows me something like:

[image]

Comment: Not quite, as I just need the unique AttrName, I'll need to process each attribute name in the application: foreach attrname, insert it into shop, get attrname_id, foreach value of that attrname insert it into shop with that attrname_id But your suggestion got me to find the solution, so I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Also, I need to process the attributes manually, as some are attributes in the eye of the shop, like shoe_size which can separate variations, and some are features like weight, which the customer doesn't select on,and some are not to be used at all

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on @mark_s

```sql
SELECT distinct AttrName = attr.value('@name', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM   product_xml
CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('/product/attribute-list/attribute') as T2(attr)
```